# What is wrong with this code for copying data from one workbook to another workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy one column of data (I want to at least copy cell value) from one workbook, and then to paste/update that copied data to a different workbook. First, I created a command button in the source workbook, so every time I click that button, all the data would update itself from another file.

This is the code that I have. It would only copy one cell at a time instead of copying a whole column.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim itemCapRet As String
Dim Testing1 As Workbook

Worksheets("Testing2").Select
itemCapRet = Range("I1")

Set myData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\Testings\Testing2.xlsx")
Worksheets("sheet1").Select
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Select
RowCount = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
.Offset(RowCount, 0) = itemCapRet
.Offset(RowCount, 1) = itemPrice
End With
Testing1.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will set the active workbook's `Testing2` Sheet,  Column `I`, to that of Column `A` on worksheet `Sheet1` in Workbook located at `C:\Documents\Testings\Testing2.xlsx`

```
Sub CopyColumn()
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim WB2 As Workbook

Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\Testings\Testing2.xlsx")

WB1.Sheets("Testing2").Columns("I").Value = WB2.Sheets("sheet1").Columns("A").Value

WB2.Close
End Sub
```

***UPDATE:*** Code based on comments:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\zyu\Documents\Processed Data\Allagash\16 cells\Copy of TXM10421_24M_capacity_102113.xls")

wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("S").Value = wb2.Sheets("16").Columns("N").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: VBA error showed up when I tried this vba code. It says Run-timer error "438": Object doesn't support this property or method. I am trying to use another transfer another set of data to another workbook without using copy and paste coding. It is because it has been giving me trouble at times.

Comment: @user2895279 What line gets highlighted when you click debug?

Comment: Line 6. 

This is what I have as my VBA code.
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook

    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\zyu\Documents\Processed Data\Allagash\16 cells\Copy of TXM10421_24M_capacity_102113.xls")

    wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").colums("S").value = wb2.Sheets("16").colums("N").value

    End Sub

Comment: @user2895279 I updated my answer with code that I tested, it worked for me. Maybe there was a type in what you had? Give my update a shot.

Comment: @user2895279 Looking at your comment, I think you recieved that error because `colums` is spelled wrong, should be `Columns` as in my updated answer.

Comment: @user2130261 Thank you! I have adjusted my code to yours. The more use VBA the more I understand how it works. I also have another problem. What if I want to copy the data from column S4 to the end of it into another worksheet column 147 to column xxx? Could I do wb1.sheets("sheet1").Range("D147", Range("D147").End(xlToLeft)).Value = wb2.Sheet("16").Range("O4", Range("O4").End(xlToLeft)).Value ??

Comment: I have adjusted my code to yours. The more use VBA the more I understand how it works. I also have another problem. What if I want to copy the data from column S4 to the end of it into another worksheet column 147 to column xxx? Could I do wb1.sheets("sheet1").Range("D147", Range("D147").End(xlToLeft)).Value = wb2.Sheet("16").Range("O4", Range("O4").End(xlToLeft)).Value ??

Comment: @user2895279 That will not work as you are setting 147 cells to a reference of 4 cells. But I do feel that is a new question and you should start a new question for that, in themean while if you feel i have answered your original question to your satisfaction feel free to accept my answer as the correct answer by clicking the Check Mark next to my answer.

Comment: Oh. Sorry I'm new to this forum. I didn't know the check is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems.  I'd suggest starting small and then building up what you want.

You're not referencing the workbooks correctly. You define myData & Testing1 but never use it.

Also, your doing a row count on a single row.

itemPrice is never set.

Your saving the Testing1 workbook but your not changing anything from it.

There are still a lot of logic problems but this will get you started.  Not sure what workbook your copying from and too exactly.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim itemCapRet As String
    Dim wbk_Testing1 As Workbook
    Dim wbk_Current As Workbook
    Set wbk_Current = ActiveWorkbook

    Set wbk_Testing1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\Testings\Testing2.xlsx")
    wbk_Testing1.Worksheets(1).Columns("A:A").Copy

    wbk_Current.Worksheets("Testing2").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    wbk_Testing1.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: I simplified the code to just copy column A from Testing1 workbook into current workbook on sheet Testing2. to give you an idea of where to start.

Comment: I appreciate your quick feedback and comment. I just started using VBA a few weeks ago and have no ideas how everything works. I have never written any codes in my lifetime until I started using this. Hm. I just want to have a command button to do copy and paste from one workbook to another workbook.

Comment: I just tried your code. It would just copy one cell from the source and paste just one cell in the other workbook. How would I copy a whole column of I?

Comment: Welcome to VBA! Best way to learn VBA is by recording macros of yourself doing small steps and then modifying the code to suite.  Make sure you look at my edited post, it is copying the whole A:A column not just one cell.

Comment: You should always avoid using selects, and whenever possible avoid copy and paste and just set the values of the destination = to the values of the copyfrom range.

Answer (score 0):

Your macro is not copying any data aside from the contents of the cell J1 in Testing2. What ranges are you trying to copy?

If you are trying to copy and paste an entire column, changing 
 `itemCapRet = Range("I1")` to `itemCapRet = Range("I:I")` 
to copy all of column J, but as Portland Runner just answered, there's a lot being defined here that isn't being used.

Comment: What if I want to copy a range that starts from D4 instead of from the beginning?